# How to map object coordinate to the screen in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

I am not able to understand the correct way of transforming primitive coordinate values to the screen coordinates.
If I use the following code (where w and h are width and height of my window 640 X 480)

```
glViewport(0,0,w,h);

// set up the projection matrix
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

// clear any previous transform and set to the identity matrix
glLoadIdentity();

// just use an orthographic projection
glOrtho(0,w,h,0,1,-1);
```

and my primitives are

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    glVertex3f(-10,-10,0);

    glColor3f(0,1,0);
    glVertex3f(10,-10,0);

    glColor3f(0,0,1);
    glVertex3f(0,10,0);

glEnd();
```

The triangle becomes too big to fit the window. Most of the tutorials have the primitives in the range[-1,1] and their ortho projection between [-1,1], so the triangle comes correctly at the centre.

So, if the coordinates are generated by a 3rd party software (or lies above the range [-1,1], how would I transform them correctly so that the coordinates fit the screen?

Comment: *"The triangle becomes too big to fit the window."* - did you mean to small? Note, you use an orthographic projection `glOrtho(0,w,h,0,1,-1);`. If  `w` and `h` are the width and height of the viewport, then the vertex coordinates are mapped 1:1 to window coordinates. In other words 10 are 10 pixel.

Comment: no - the triangle size is too large that only partial triangle can be seen in the window..

Comment: But the code in the question would do so! So in your program `glOrtho` is never set or `w` respectively `h` are not the width and height of the window. Or the projection matrix is cleared after it was set. Any way this is not a [How to create a Minimal, **Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)